# `$ git push heroku main` fails. (Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - npx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, npx

I am having trouble deploying an app I built in rails on heroku.
I was able to deploy on Fly.io but could not reflect my own domain, so now I am trying to deploy on Heroku.

When I run the "git push heroku main" command to deploy, it fails with the error **"Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - npx".**

I can check the version of npx, so I don't know why I am getting this error.

```
% npx --version
8.15.0
```

I would like to know how to resolve this error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "csso-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "daisyui": "^2.49.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
#web: unset PORT && bin/rails server
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

**Back End**

- Ruby 3.1.3
- Ruby on Rails 7.0.4

**Front End**

- JavaScript
- Tailswind CSS-daisyUI

**Infrastructure**

- PostgreSQL
- AWS(Amazon S3)

**Error logs**

```
% git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 7085, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7085/7085), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6654/6654), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7085/7085), 23.67 MiB | 509.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7085 (delta 1141), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.6
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.6
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.2.0
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.17.0
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.12.0
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing erubi 1.12.0
remote:        Fetching racc 1.6.2
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing minitest 5.17.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.2.0
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.6.2
remote:        Installing racc 1.6.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.6.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Fetching marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Installing marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching date 3.3.3
remote:        Installing date 3.3.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching timeout 0.3.1
remote:        Installing timeout 0.3.1
remote:        Fetching public_suffix 5.0.1
remote:        Installing public_suffix 5.0.1
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.18
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.18 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.6.0
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 2.3.26
remote:        Fetching byebug 11.1.3
remote:        Installing byebug 11.1.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching cancancan 3.4.0
remote:        Installing cancancan 3.4.0
remote:        Fetching mini_magick 4.12.0
remote:        Installing mini_magick 4.12.0
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.15.5
remote:        Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ssrf_filter 1.1.1
remote:        Installing ssrf_filter 1.1.1
remote:        Fetching coderay 1.1.3
remote:        Installing coderay 1.1.3
remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Installing method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching thor 1.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.6.6
remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.6.6
remote:        Fetching dotenv 2.8.1
remote:        Installing dotenv 2.8.1
remote:        Fetching excon 0.98.0
remote:        Installing excon 0.98.0
remote:        Fetching faraday-net_http 3.0.2
remote:        Installing faraday-net_http 3.0.2
remote:        Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
remote:        Fetching formatador 1.1.0
remote:        Installing formatador 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Fetching hashie 5.0.0
remote:        Installing hashie 5.0.0
remote:        Fetching jwt 2.6.0
remote:        Installing jwt 2.6.0
remote:        Fetching kaminari-core 1.2.2
remote:        Installing kaminari-core 1.2.2
remote:        Fetching multi_xml 0.6.0
remote:        Installing multi_xml 0.6.0
remote:        Fetching nested_form 0.3.2
remote:        Installing nested_form 0.3.2
remote:        Fetching version_gem 1.1.1
remote:        Installing version_gem 1.1.1
remote:        Fetching pg 1.4.5
remote:        Installing pg 1.4.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.11
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.11
remote:        Fetching rack-test 2.0.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 2.0.2
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.12.0
remote:        Installing i18n 1.12.0
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 2.0.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 2.0.5
remote:        Fetching sprockets 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 4.2.0
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching net-protocol 0.2.1
remote:        Installing net-protocol 0.2.1
remote:        Fetching addressable 2.8.1
remote:        Installing addressable 2.8.1
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.14.0 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.14.0 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Fetching puma 5.6.5
remote:        Installing puma 5.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching pry 0.14.2
remote:        Installing pry 0.14.2
remote:        Fetching faraday 2.7.4
remote:        Installing faraday 2.7.4
remote:        Fetching mime-types 3.4.1
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.4.1
remote:        Fetching snaky_hash 2.0.1
remote:        Installing snaky_hash 2.0.1
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.16.0
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.16.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching activesupport 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching net-pop 0.1.2
remote:        Installing net-pop 0.1.2
remote:        Fetching net-smtp 0.3.3
remote:        Installing net-smtp 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.19.1
remote:        Installing loofah 2.19.1
remote:        Fetching net-imap 0.3.4
remote:        Installing net-imap 0.3.4
remote:        Fetching pry-byebug 3.10.1
remote:        Installing pry-byebug 3.10.1
remote:        Fetching fog-core 2.3.0
remote:        Installing fog-core 2.3.0
remote:        Fetching oauth 0.6.2
remote:        Installing oauth 0.6.2
remote:        Fetching oauth2 2.0.9
remote:        Installing oauth2 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 1.1.0
remote:        Installing globalid 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.5.0
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.5.0
remote:        Fetching mail 2.8.0.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.8.0.1
remote:        Fetching fog-json 1.2.0
remote:        Installing fog-json 1.2.0
remote:        Fetching fog-xml 0.1.4
remote:        Installing fog-xml 0.1.4
remote:        Fetching sorcery 0.16.4
remote:        Installing sorcery 0.16.4
remote:        Fetching activejob 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing activejob 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching activerecord 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching activemodel-serializers-xml 1.0.2
remote:        Installing activemodel-serializers-xml 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionview 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actionview 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching fog-aws 3.16.0
remote:        Fetching kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
remote:        Installing kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
remote:        Fetching ransack 3.2.1
remote:        Installing ransack 3.2.1
remote:        Installing fog-aws 3.16.0
remote:        Fetching seed-fu 2.3.9
remote:        Installing seed-fu 2.3.9
remote:        Fetching actionpack 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.11.5
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.11.5
remote:        Fetching kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
remote:        Installing kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
remote:        Fetching actioncable 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching activestorage 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing activestorage 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching railties 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing railties 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching meta-tags 2.18.0
remote:        Installing meta-tags 2.18.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Fetching kaminari 1.2.2
remote:        Installing kaminari 1.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailbox 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching actiontext 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actionmailbox 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing actiontext 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching cssbundling-rails 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching dotenv-rails 2.8.1
remote:        Installing dotenv-rails 2.8.1
remote:        Installing cssbundling-rails 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching gretel 4.4.0
remote:        Fetching jsbundling-rails 1.1.1
remote:        Installing gretel 4.4.0
remote:        Installing jsbundling-rails 1.1.1
remote:        Fetching rails-i18n 7.0.6
remote:        Fetching turbo-rails 1.3.2
remote:        Installing turbo-rails 1.3.2
remote:        Installing rails-i18n 7.0.6
remote:        Fetching stimulus-rails 1.2.1
remote:        Installing stimulus-rails 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching rails 7.0.4.2
remote:        Installing rails 7.0.4.2
remote:        Fetching rails_admin 3.1.1
remote:        Installing rails_admin 3.1.1
remote:        Fetching ruby-vips 2.1.4
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.4.0
remote:        Installing ruby-vips 2.1.4
remote:        Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching image_processing 1.12.2
remote:        Installing image_processing 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching carrierwave 2.2.3
remote:        Installing carrierwave 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Bundle complete! 34 Gemfile dependencies, 107 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Post-install message from oauth:
remote:        
remote:        You have installed oauth version 0.6.2, congratulations!
remote:        
remote:        Non-commercial support for the 0.6.x series will end by April, 2024. Please upgrade to 1.0.x as soon as possible!
remote:        The only breaking change will be dropped support for Ruby 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6.
remote:        
remote:        Please see:
remote:        • https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/blob/main/SECURITY.md
remote:        
remote:        Note also that I am, and this project is, in the process of leaving Github.
remote:        I wrote about some of the reasons here:
remote:        • https://dev.to/galtzo/im-leaving-github-50ba
remote:        
remote:        If you are a human, please consider a donation as I move toward supporting myself with Open Source work:
remote:        • https://liberapay.com/pboling
remote:        • https://ko-fi.com/pboling
remote:        • https://patreon.com/galtzo
remote:        
remote:        If you are a corporation, please consider supporting this project, and open source work generally, with a TideLift subscription.
remote:        • https://tidelift.com/funding/github/rubygems/oauth
remote:        • Or hire me. I am looking for a job!
remote:        
remote:        Please report issues, and support the project!
remote:        
remote:        Thanks, |7eter l-|. l3oling
remote:        Post-install message from oauth2:
remote:        
remote:        You have installed oauth2 version 2.0.9, congratulations!
remote:        
remote:        There are BREAKING changes if you are upgrading from < v2, but most will not encounter them, and updating your code should be easy!
remote:        
remote:        We have made two other major migrations:
remote:        1. master branch renamed to main
remote:        2. Github has been replaced with Gitlab
remote:        
remote:        Please see:
remote:        • https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2#what-is-new-for-v20
remote:        • https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
remote:        • https://groups.google.com/g/oauth-ruby/c/QA_dtrXWXaE
remote:        
remote:        Please report issues, and support the project! Thanks, |7eter l-|. l3oling
remote:        
remote:        Post-install message from rails_admin:
remote:        
remote:            ### Upgrading RailsAdmin from 2.x.x to 3.x.x ###
remote:        
remote:            Due to introduction of Webpack/Webpacker support, some additional dependencies and configuration will be needed.
remote:            Running `bin/rails g rails_admin:install` will suggest required changes, based on the current setup of your app.
remote:        
remote:            For a complete list of changes, see https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
remote:          Post-install message from sorcery:
remote:        As of version 1.0 oauth/oauth2 won't be automatically bundled so you may need to add those dependencies to your Gemfile.
remote:        You may need oauth2 if you use external providers such as any of these: https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/tree/master/lib/sorcery/providers
remote:        Bundle completed (90.93s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing bundler (2.3.25)
remote: -----> Installing node-v16.18.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.19
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        yarn install v1.22.19
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 5.02s.
remote:        yarn run v1.22.19
remote:        $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
remote:        
remote:          app/assets/builds/application.js      492.4kb
remote:          app/assets/builds/application.js.map  882.0kb
remote:        
remote:        Done in 0.15s.
remote:        yarn install v1.22.19
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        success Already up-to-date.
remote:        Done in 0.11s.
remote:        yarn run v1.22.19
remote:        $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify
remote:        
remote:        Rebuilding...
remote:        
remote:         daisyUI components 2.49.0  https://daisyui.com
remote:          ✔︎ Including:  base, components, 1 themes, utilities
remote:          ❤︎ Support daisyUI:  https://opencollective.com/daisyui 
remote:          
remote:        
remote:        Done in 967ms.
remote:        Done in 1.60s.
remote:        [CssoCompressor] Compressing…
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - npx
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/config/initializers/csso.rb:14:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:204:in `block in fetch_or_store'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:184:in `fetch'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:203:in `fetch_or_store'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:32:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:31:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:204:in `block in fetch_or_store'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:184:in `fetch'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:203:in `fetch_or_store'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
remote:        /tmp/build_6a972009/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.0/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to hontobutai.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hontobutai.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hontobutai.git'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `npx` on Heroku in the first place? Please show us your `package.json` and, if you have one, your `Procfile`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added `package.json` and `Procfile`. I was not aware of npx when I created the application and only learned of the word when the error occurred.
I am a beginner, so I am not sure why the error occurred.

Comment: Oh, this is a Rails app? Nothing in the original question suggested that at all. Please edit the complete error message with traceback into your question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it better. I added error logs and information on technology used. If there's any information I'm missing, please let me know.